# How do I use a user input and insert it in a pre-determined text in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo, user-input

I am trying to catch the user input and add it to specific text, which will be sent to the clipboard.

```batch-file
@echo off set /p TICKETID="Enter Ticket #: " 
echo Here is the ticket for you, thanks : %TICKETID% 
pause & ECHO |Here is the ticket for you, thanks : %TICKETID%| CLIP
```

This will not work I tried other ways to code it, like:

```batch-file
@echo off
set /p userInput="Enter Ticket #: "

REM Get current clipboard content
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell -command "Get-Clipboard"`) do set "clipboardContent=%%I"

REM Define the phrase in clipboard
set "phrase=Here is the ticket for you, thanks:"

REM Combine user input with the phrase
set "newClipboardContent=%clipboardContent% %phrase% %userInput%"

REM Set the new content back to clipboard
echo %newClipboardContent% | clip
```

This also failed to do it.

I was trying also with:

```batch-file
@echo off
SET /P variable=Enter ticket # :
echo Here is a ticket for you %variable% | CLIP
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: "will not work" is not useful as a problem description. It means "did not do what I expected", but you haven't stated what you expected. To format code, select the code and press `{}`. I tried that on your post, but cannot be sure that the result is what you intended. You can press `edit` to edit your post. I tried your third example and it did what **I** expected it to do; that is, prompt for input. then post `Here is a t…ou numberentered` to the clipboard, Running the batch, entering `abc123` at the prompt and then `^V` whowed `Here is a ticket for you abc123`. Is this code in parentheses?

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:PowerShell]?

Answer (score 0):

Here is with a simple way to achieve your aim :

```bash
@echo off
Set /p TICKETID="Enter Ticket #: "
echo Here is the ticket for you, thanks : %TICKETID%
echo Here is the ticket for you, thanks : %TICKETID% | CLIP
echo Copied to the clipboard
pause
```